# How to format deduction/equation extending multiple pages?

Tags: page-breaking, logic

I'm working on a logic paper that includes a deduction of one of DeMorgan's laws. The proof is Fitch style using Johan Klüwer's 2003 [`fitch.sty`](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/fitch.sty) package. It's a long proof and I inevitably end up with a page number and break in the middle of the proof. I'm sure there's a tedious manual way to break the proof and start on the next page with the correct numbering for each step in the proof. However I'm looking for a more dynamic solution, that I assume exists for generic equations. I'm somewhat aware of `\allowdisplaybreaks` but it doesn't seem to work for me (`fitch.sty` might be creating unbreakable boxes?). I've copied the deduction bellow and appreciate all help.

```
\documentclass[ 11pt]{article}


\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fitch}



\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
\begin{fitch}
\fh \lnot (A \land B)  \\
\fa A \lor \lnot A \\
\fa\fh A \\
\fa\fa\fh B \\
\fa\fa\fa A \land B & 3, 4 \\
\fa\fa\fa \bot & 1, 5 \\
\fa\fa \lnot B & 4--6 \\
\fa\fa \lnot A \lor \lnot B & 7 \\
\fa A \to (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) & 3--8 \\
\fa\fh \lnot A \\
\fa\fa \lnot A \lor \lnot B & 10 \\
\fa \lnot A \to (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)  & 10--11\\
\fa \lnot A \lor \lnot B & 2, 9, 12 \\
\lnot (A \land B)\to (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) & 1--13 \\
\fh \lnot A \lor \lnot B \\
\fa\fh \lnot A \\
\fa\fa\fh A \land B \\
\fa\fa\fa A & 17 \\
\fa\fa\fa \bot & 16, 18 \\
\fa\fa \lnot (A \land B) & 17--19 \\
\fa \lnot A \to \lnot (A \land B) & 16--20 \\
\fa\fh \lnot B \\
\fa\fa\fh A \land B \\
\fa\fa\fa B & 23 \\
\fa\fa\fa \bot & 22, 24 \\
\fa\fa \lnot (A \land B) & 23--25\\
\fa \lnot B \to \lnot (A \land B) & 22--26 \\
\fa \lnot (A \land B) & 15, 21, 27 \\
(\lnot A \lor \lnot B ) \to \lnot (A \land B) & 15--28\\
(\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \iff \lnot (A \land B) & 14, 29\\
\end{fitch}
\end{equation*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `fitch` environment creates a `tabular` that so cannot be broken across pages. Please, make a compilable example.

Comment: You don't seem to be using `fitch.sty` as you claim. At least, not the `fitch.sty` I've got.

Comment: example should now compile using the `fitch.sty` that I link to. I know that there are other `fitch.sty` packages out there such as the one by Peter Selinger.

Comment: As egreg says, it uses `tabular` so can't be broken across pages.

Comment: It is nesting boxes, I think. The easiest way to split it would be to create an image and then include it twice, cropping the image above and below the appropriate point.